# Use an external function as a method of a class

Tags: c++, class, methods

I'm trying to make this code work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int f(int x) {
    return x+1;
}

class A {
    public:
    int g(int y);
};

int A::g(int y) = f;


int main() {
    A test;
    cout << test.g(3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It does not compile because of the line `int A::g(int y) = f;`.
What is the correct way to achieve that an external function can be used as a method?

Comment: `int A::g(int y) { return f(); }`. That's not what the question is asking for, but non-member functions and member functions are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pointer to function as a member of class `A`. Now assign function `f` to `g` member of `A`.

```
int f(int x) {
    return x+1;
}

class A {
    public:
    int (*g)(int);
};

int main(){
    A test;
    test.g = f;
    cout << test.g(10); // prints 11
}
```

Comment: Is this less efficient than a direct implementation? From my understanding of C++ there is any difference when compiled with flags, but I'd like to be sure

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the same by making your function a callable objects by implementing `()` operator. so you can have that as member of the class, and then it can normally be used as function on the class objects.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct do_something{
    int operator()(int num){
        return num;
    }
};
class test{
    int sum;
    public:
        do_something fun;
};

int main(){
    test obj;
    std::cout << obj.fun(10);
}
```